# InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file://user:password@/localhost/log/service.log

Tags: spring-boot, java.nio.file

I am creating a spring-boot web application which has to read data from a log file located on a remote server.
The path of the log file on the remote server is constructed as follows:
`file://user:password@/localhost/log/service.log`

I am using the `Paths.get()` method to access the log file.
However I am getting the following error:

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file://user:password@/localhost/log/service.log
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    ...
```

Can anyone tell me if the path I have constructed is correct for reading a file?
If no, then what it should be? 
And if yes, how can I resolve the error?

Comment: where have you specified remote server ip or hostname?

Comment: @pvpkiran The remote server details like ip, log file name and path are stored in a properties file that is read when constructing the file path.

Comment: But as you can see from the logs, ip is not appended, it should be there after ''@'

Comment: It can be the IP of the server or the name itself, as in this case seen in the log it is "localhost".

Comment: Also when I changed the path as follows:
**file://user:password@localhost/log/service.log**
I still got the same exception. For that matter I got the same exception when I added the port to the path in the following format:
**file://user:password@localhost:8080/log/service.log**